# Get Collection from complicated query

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

For example, I need to get city name in search field. City, as Model, has its own `name` and `region` string columns. I need to get Collection in order like:

1. Cities with name `ilike` input value
2. Cities with region `ilike` input value
3. Other cities.

Answer (score 0):

```
City::where(['name'=>'ilike','region'=>'ilike'])->get() - It it is equivalent to - Select * from cities where region = 'ilike' and name = 'ilike'
or maybe you mean this 
1.City::where('name','ilike')->get() ;
2.City::where('region','ilike')->get();
3.City::where('region',"!=",'ilike')->where('name',"!=",'ilike')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to use it. As about meaning I want to make collection, sorted by those 3 rules in one query, to carry it in one variable.

Comment: Can you use this option City::orderby('name')->orderby('region')->get()? [Ordering, Grouping, Limit & Offset](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#ordering)